# How to customize an auth of multi auth in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I found the way to add an admin guard.

But there are no documentation to customize the following functionality:

```
Auth::guard('admin')->attempt()
Auth::guard('admin')->user()
Auth::guard('admin')->check()
middleware('auth:admin')
```

I need to check an additional field of admin table to check if the admin can be logged in.

In `Auth::guard('admin')->attempt()`, I want to use SQL like this:

```
Admin::where('login_id', $request->input('login_id'))
    ->where('password', md5($request->input('password')))
    ->where('additional_field', [additional condition]);
```

By `Auth::guard('admin')->user()`, I want to get the result of SQL like this:

```
Admin::where('id', Auth::guard('admin')->id())
    ->where('additional_field', [additional condition]);
```

And both `Auth::guard('admin')->check()` and `middleware('auth:admin')` also should consider the additional condition in the code above.

Is there a way to customize them?

And, are there any other functionalities of Laravel's auth which I have to customize to satisfy the requirement of the additional condition above?

I'm using Laravel 8.

Comment: the docs show you how to specify additional conditions when calling `attempt` ... `check` isn't doing anything but seeing if their is a user authenticated

Comment: @lagbox thank you for the information. the specifying additional conditions might be enough for the current requirements of my project. but the requirements in the future might become more complex than that. i will not use laravel's auth because `check` or `user` or `middleware's auth` can not be customized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF your `additional stuff` are some input like `login_id` and `password`
maybe this should work.

```
$cradentials= $request->only('email','password','additional stuff');
if( Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($cradentials) ){

       //stuff here
     }
```